# Conditional creating a bean based on customized biz logic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

Here're my use case:

When my app launched, N beans of type A will be created.

I'd like to have my own biz logic to check these N beans 1 by 1 and:

- if none of them satisfy my criteria, I'll create another bean of type A to spring container.
- if any of them satisfy my criteria, just do nothing.

I'm not sure whether I can simply use Optional like this:

```
@Autowired
List<A> beans;

@Bean
public Optional<A> maybeA(){
  //check beans and optionally create a A
}
```

Comment: Check for `GenericBeanDefinition` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537481/spring-dynamic-bean-creation-depending-on-other-bean

Comment: You could annotate `maybeA` with `@Conditional`. But this case you only have access to the bean definitions, not the bean instances itself. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html

Answer (score 0):

Defining bean that returns type Optional is very unusual and not a good solution.I suggest you check if you could implement your logic as described https://iamninad.com/conditional-bean-creation-in-spring-boot/ or if you insist to follow your solution,  you can create a new class as :

```
public class UnMatchedACriteriaImpl implements A {

   public void testMethod() throws UnSatisfiedXCriteria {
       throw new UnSatisfiedXCriteria();
   }
}
```

and change your bean definition to :

```
@Bean
public A maybeA(){
  //check beans and optionally create a A
}
```

When you criteria does not match you return `UnMatchedACriteriaImpl` version of `A`. which is clear and manageable when you want to use it in your application.